# Term for someone who does more for strangers than family for friends

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a word to describe (from a family or friend's perspective) a person that would go out of their way to do more for a stranger than for their family and friends.

I am also wondering if there would be different words if the reason or motivation for doing this is different, e.g. if this person's family is rich and doesn't need money so they give money to other people to help them out, or if this person doesn't feel close to their family (or treats them the same as strangers).

Comment: Has anyone heard a word "philoxenia" or "xenophilia"? I consider anyone who shows love and hospitality to strangers to be a less-biased person, an opposite of someone who's "xenophobic". But in the meantime, I worry if such "philoxenic" person is viewed by his family as "familiaphobic"!

Comment: What about, just simply, "humble"? I think "servile" as well, but there is a sense of sycophancy in that one. Lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theoxeny**
I recall this term from Greek mythology, but I don't know of it equates to love of strangers *compared* to family

[1]: http://Xenia (Greek: ξενία, xenía, trans. ... Theoxeny or theoxenia is a theme in Greek mythology in which human beings demonstrate their virtue or piety by extending hospitality to a humble stranger (xenos), who turns out to be a disguised deity (theos) with the capacity to bestow rewards.

Xenia (Greek) - Wikipedia

What the OP describes is an extremely common psychological phenomenon. I'm interested if there's a more specific answer.